# Real Time update in Android application

Tags: android, json

I work on an android application which linked to a web application using json, I need to get the last data from web app to my android app, there's some tools to cheeck if there're any update in the web app and notify the android app ?
I do that but it takes time, I get json from web app and I see time of the last storage value, if the same of my android app I skip else I parse Json.
Do yo know any alternative to do that ?
I use Realm to parse and store data, Volley to communicate with the web app.

Comment: Have you never heard of push messages? Your app asking your server if there is anything new is a terrible strategy - your server telling your app that there is new content is a much much better alternative.

Comment: Yes, so do you have any tools to get my work easly ? some names ?

Comment: Have you looked at Firebase realtime database?

Comment: Yes I saw Firebase, but I need a free tool

Comment: A free tool? Nobody is just going to offer you a service out of the kindness of their hearts. If you use it commercially then you have to pay for it.  And by the way: Firebase has a free level. You only have to pay if you want to go beyond any of the limits in the free version.

Comment: Firebase can do anything you want. And Firebase cloud messaging is completely free. Just look at the Android or Firebase developer page, there are dozens of guides.

Comment: I would say use socket.io on your server and implement accordingly by using socket.io in client app as well.